# Hex Hash Comparison

Tags: mysql, hash, comparison, hex, padding

I store hashes on a table as type `bit(64)`. Some of these hash records cannot be retrieved by directly matching them via a `select`.
**Explanation:**

I insert each hash in the DB with the command

```
insert into hashes (id, hash) values (0, 0xad66f2f8f3815456);
```

Then, I retrieve the record with

```
select id from hashes where hex(hash) = 'ad66f2f8f3815456';
+------+
| id   |
+------+
|    0 |
+------+
```

This works for as long as the hash isn't zero-padded:

```
insert into hashes (id, hash) values (1, 0x0d66f2f8f3815456);
select id from hashes where hex(hash) = '0d66f2f8f3815456';
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

Retrieving the record by matching the ID instead results in:

```
select id, hex(hash) from hashes where id = 1;
+------+-----------------+
| id   | hex(hash)       |
+------+-----------------+
|    1 | D66F2F8F3815456 |
+------+-----------------+
```

so I think I'm not able to make a numeric match between the stored hash and the one prompted, regardless of the padding zeros. The table I'm using is:

```
describe hashes;
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id    | int(4)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| hash  | bit(64) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

How is this solvable? Is this the proper way to handle records of 64-bit hashes which require a numerical comparison?
I have several thousands of these records, so they shouldn't probably be stored as cumbersome varchars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indexed varchars actually work pretty well, but you can also achieve the same result by using an [unsigned bigint](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html), if you're always using a 64-bit value, and can easily convert to the numeric representation of the hash code.

Comment: I think that switching to unsigned bigint is the only solution to permit zero-padded numeric comparison. I have no idea why `select 0x00000ffff = 0xffff` returns 0, while `select 0x00000ffff = cast(0xffff as unsigned integer)` returns 1.

Comment: Because `0xffff` is a short int `-1`, and not the same as `0x0ffff` which is `65536`.